# How to combine import all with others?

Tags: typescript

I am getting from TSLint:

```
Multiple imports from 'moment' can be combined into one.
```

Guilty code:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
```

I have tried several variants without success (I have not found relevant example in docs):

```
import * as moment, { Moment } from 'moment';
import { * as moment, Moment } from 'moment';
import { * as moment, Moment as Moment } from 'moment';
```

Comment: I am not sure about TS, but in ES 6 you can go just with `import moment, { Moment } from 'moment';` (maybe it will work for TS as well).

Comment: `import * as moment from "moment";` is correct. But only that :) Then access everything with `moment.Moment` etc.

Comment: @Wernerson I thought it could be modified like that, but when TSLint said it could be combined to one import, I thought it meant "combined to one import without modifying anything else".

Answer (score 18):

Be careful because:

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
```

is different from

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

Because the second imports only the **namespace moment** and everything within, but the first imports **everything including function moment()** that is out of the namespace.
Correct import can be:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
type Moment = moment.Moment;
```

Answer (score 12):

If you use an asterisk in import then you can access everything from the imported module by the name given `as` for the asterisk.

In this particular example:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

You don't need to import `{ Moment }` as well because you can simply access  `Moment` by `moment.Moment` in your code.

**Note**

You can't combine asterisk import with any other import and yes, in this particular case the TSLint message is a little bit misleading.

**EDIT**

As I wrote in my first comment, this ES6 way should work as well and it really works:

```
import moment, { Moment } from 'moment';
```

It was added into TS in version 1.8 (see [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html)).

> Module loaders like SystemJS wrap CommonJS modules and expose then as
>   a default ES6 import. This makes it impossible to share the definition
>   files between the SystemJS and CommonJS implementation of the module
>   as the module shape looks different based on the loader.
>
> Setting the new compiler flag --allowSyntheticDefaultImports indicates
>   that the module loader performs some kind of synthetic default import
>   member creation not indicated in the imported .ts or .d.ts. The
>   compiler will infer the existence of a default export that has the
>   shape of the entire module itself.
>
> System modules have this flag on by default.

Comment: I am understanding it right - the linter error is wrong and it can't be combined to one import without touching rest of the code?

Comment: @monnef Sort of, I still believe `import moment, {Moment} from 'moment';` should work as well but this will work for sure. On the other hand, you can't combine asterisk import with anything else and yes, in this particular case the TSLint message is a little bit misleading.

Comment: @KnutHolm `import moment, {Moment} from 'moment';` is different from `import * as moment from 'moment'; import { Moment } from 'moment';`. The first one imports the named export `Moment` from `moment` as well as importing the default export and gives it the name `moment`. The second one only imports named exports (`Moment` and `moment.Moment` would be aliases here). There's no way to access the default export with the second form.

Answer (score 8):

The below doesn't always work. It all depends if `someModule` has `default` export defined. If yes, then it will work.

```
import someModule, { someMember } from 'someModule';
```

The module I was referencing has no `default` defined, so I went with the following approach:

```
import * as someModule from 'someModule';
// To avoid multiple imports from the same module, destruct the exported members from the module.
const { someMember } = someModule;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Typescript you can export multiple functions, classes and variables from one file. In most cases you just want some particular thing of an import like:

`import { Component } from "@angular/core";`

Moment is built a little bit different so you usually import it like this:

`import * as moment from "moment";`

This can also be used in the angular import:

```
import * as AngularCore from "@angular/core";

@AngularCore.Component({
    //...
```

It's the same technique. In the second way you just assign *ALL* exports to a variable called AngularCore (or moment). This is now like a wrapper. You can imagine it like a Javascript object:

```
var AngularCore = {
    Component: // the component things....
    OnInit: // the OnInit interface...
}
```

[image: little fancy paint grahpic]

Here you can see more or less how it works. (Sorry for the bad paint skills :/ )

The variable (in the example moment) can have any name you like.

I hope you can understand this. If not just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You just do this:

```
import moment, {Moment} from 'moment';
```

In the `tsconfig.json` you should have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` set to `true` as of Typescript 1.8 (it's true by default).

Comment: I tried this for a different module but `import xyz, { rest }` only works if there is a default export and `import * as xyz, { rest }` is a syntax error.